# Posterior predictive distribution for Bernoulli (and categorical)

Tags: posterior, conjugate-prior, beta-binomial-distribution, multinomial-dirichlet-distribution

I'm trying to confirm something I've tried to figure out about the posterior predictive distribution for Bernoulli vs. Binomial (and categorical vs. multinomial) random variables after a Bayesian analysis with a conjugate prior. Let's say I have this situation:

- There's a process that involves yes/no classification and a-priori I had a $\text{Beta}(a,b)$ prior for the probability $\pi_\text{yes}$ of a yes classification.
- After seeing $n_\text{yes}$ yeses and $n_\text{no}$ nos out of $n$ classfications, I have a $\text{Beta}(a + n_\text{yes},b + n_\text{no})$ posterior for $\pi_\text{yes}$. This posterior has an expected value (mean) of $\frac{a + n_\text{yes}}{a + b + n}$.
- Now, I have $m$ new items that need classification. I know that the distribution of the yeses given our updated belief follows a $\text{beta-binomial}(m, a + n_\text{yes},b + n_\text{no})$ distribution.

However, I'm interested in simulating out what happens to each individual item as part of a larger prediction problem, where you then do subsequent steps afterwards. The marginal posterior predictive distribution of each Bernoulli trial is just a $\text{Bernoulli}(\frac{a + n_\text{yes}}{a + b + n})$. If I draw each individual item's classification from this Bernoulli, the overall mean of the predicted total number remains unchanged ($\frac{a + n_\text{yes}}{a + b + n}$), but the variance is wrong (i.e. we simulated effectively from a Binomial not a Beta-Binomial), right?

I assume the answer is that if I want 100 simulated datasets, I should first draw a single proportion $\pi_j$ for each dataset $j=1,\ldots,100$ and then simulate each Bernoulli trial in that dataset from a $\text{Bernoulli}(\pi_j)$. Is that correct?

I assume the same would apply when there's more than two categories (and we have a Dirichlet prior and want to then simulate individual categorical random variables), because otherwise we would not match the Dirichlet-Multinomial for the overall outcomes.

Comment: Yes, everything you say is correct, to simulate from the predictive Beta-Binomial distribution, first simulating $\pi_j$ from its posterior and then simulating from a binomial conditional on $\pi_j$ is indeed one way of doing it.